# Netbeans stopping interpreting PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I've got a big problem here, I don't know from where it comes, but it's realy annoying. I'm working on a project using HTML5,CSS3 and angularjs. I added a simple function into my JS and then everything stopped working: all my js is broken ^^' I'll show you what it does:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQWTe.png)

the text goes green and if I click on it, it highlights my function. This on every next controller I have. Everything was working fine till I added:

```
   $scope.suppUtilisateurOnClick = function(utilisateur) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: livre,
                    url: 'myurl'
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log("okay");
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(response);
                });
            };
```

on my second controller... I don't know what it is, thanks in advance.